# How to get the time difference in seconds?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have used Jodha Library and tried to get the difference between two dates in seconds. But it is only accurate up to the date. Not to the seconds.

```
 public static int getDateDifference(DateTime dateCreatedPa)
    {
        LocalDate dateCreated = new LocalDate (dateCreatedPa);
        LocalDate now = new LocalDate();

        Seconds secondsBetween = Seconds.secondsBetween(dateCreated, now);

        return secondsBetween.getSeconds();
    }
       ///code calling the above method

        DateTime dateCreated=new DateTime(drivingLicense.getDateCreated());
        int dateDiff=Common.getDateDifference(dateCreated);            
        request.setAttribute("dateDiff", dateDiff);

        System.out.println("Timestamp: "+dateDiff);
```

This shows the date difference. But if I give different times on the same date for comparison, it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) is just that, date only, no time information.  Use [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.Seconds;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime today = DateTime.now();
        today = today.minusDays(5);
        int dateDiff = getDateDifference(today);
        System.out.println("Timestamp: " + dateDiff);
    }

    public static int getDateDifference(DateTime dateCreatedPa) {
        LocalDateTime dateCreated = new LocalDateTime(dateCreatedPa);
        LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime();

        System.out.println(dateCreated);
        System.out.println(now);

        Seconds secondsBetween = Seconds.secondsBetween(dateCreated, now);

        return secondsBetween.getSeconds();
    }

}
```

Outputs...

```
2015-02-27T15:20:56.524
2015-03-04T15:20:56.628
Timestamp: 432000
```